# Edit Macros for Include Directories Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, macros, include

I've downloaded an open source project I'd like to play around with. In it's include directories it uses a macro called $(UserLibraries). I've already placed the proper libraries in a folder, now how can I edit that macro to point at the folder on my harddrive, instead of the original owners? Double clicking it, right clicking, etc, does nothing.

Here is specifically what it looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GP7ha.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the vcxproj file directly in any text editor and change it there. i find this to be much easier than using the gui.

Comment: You can add $(UserLibraries), but you cannot define it if it is not defined.

Comment: You don't find that in your project file.

Comment: 1., thats not what I said. 2., yes, you most certainly can define your own. `<PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros"> <PathToFoo>c:\somePath\</PathToFoo></PropertyGroup>`. Then you can do something like `<ClCompile><AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(PathToFoo)\bar\baz\include</AdditionalIncludeDirectories></ClCompile>`